# While loop - reading two lines at a time

Tags: bash, logs

I am trying to parse data from a log file.

Here is the datafile in:

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
Data4
```

My code is as follow:

```
data=$(cat datafile)
echo "$data" | while read line; read line1;
do
    echo "$line and $line1"
done
```

My desired output is:

```
Data1 and Data2
Data2 and Data3
Data3 and Data4
```

But instead I get:

```
Data1 and Data2
Data3 and Data4
```

I do understand why I get this behavior, however I am short on ideas about how to do as I want. Does anybody happen to know a trick?

Thanks

Comment: That code sample will fail, and can't possibly produce the output you say it does. Please double-check what you've given us.

Comment: Missed a line yeah, my bad :)

Comment: You could store the datafile into an array and do a loop to output "line[i] and line[i+1]".

Comment: I made the final edit on the post but it does work though.The idea of an array could be useful, i'll try that!

Comment: @dr01 there's a dup of this - I saw it only a couple of days ago - just trying to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How far would

```
{ read line
  while read line1
  do
     echo $line and $line1
     line=$line1
  done
 } < datafile 

Data1 and Data2
Data2 and Data3
Data3 and Data4
```

get you?

Comment: Bingo. Are the brackets the key to this? By the way it works for me now, but I'm considering investigating Stephane Chazelas answer furthermore, it seems to be the best practice one.

Comment: The braces enclose a "compund command" which in turn makes sure both leading `read` and `while` loop use the same , redirected input.  Without them, the `while` loop would reopen it at line 1. I didn't use `awk` as I thought you need to perform other shell tasks on each data pair.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't use shell `while read` loops to process text](/q/169716). Here it's easiest with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print prev, "and", $0}; {prev = $0}' < datafile
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed 'x; 1d; G; s/\n/ and /' < datafile
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm currently reading all of your good practices answers in others posts. You could write a book named "you are using bash wrong" :)

Answer (score 1):

One more while read loop...

```
while read -r line; do 
  printf '%s and %s\n' "$line" "$line"
done < data
```

Or

```
while read -r line <&3; do 
  read -r line1
  printf '%s and %s\n' "$line" "$line1"
done 3< data < data
```

or bash4+ mapfile

```
mapfile -t array < data

for i in "${!array[@]}"; do 
  printf '%s and %s\n' "${array[$i]}" "${array[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply paste the file to its clone with the first line removed:

```
$ tail -n+2 datafile | paste datafile -
```